# C# - how to parallel code that lock several object one by one

Tags: c#, locking

I have such code:

```
public void TablesUpdated(object sender, TablesUpdatedArgs args)
{
    lock (quotesLock)
    {
        while (!args.quotesQueue.IsNullOrEmpty())
            quotes.Enqueue(args.quotesQueue.Dequeue());
    }
    lock (securitiesLock)
    {
        while (!args.securitiesUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            securities.Enqueue(args.securitiesUpdates.Dequeue());
    }
    lock (orderUpdatesLock)
    {
        while (!args.orderUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            orderUpdates.Enqueue(args.orderUpdates.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that i'm waiting for `lock` while i can likely process other parts of code. And while i'm waiting it's possible that other parts of code will be locked!

Let's assume that `quotesLock` is busy between 0 and 1 second, `securitiesLock` is busy between 1 and 2 second and `orderUpdatesLock` is busy between 2 and 3 second. My code will be blocked for 3 seconods totally because of order.

But if `qoutesLock` will be the last:

```
public void TablesUpdated(object sender, TablesUpdatedArgs args)
{
    lock (securitiesLock)
    {
        while (!args.securitiesUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            securities.Enqueue(args.securitiesUpdates.Dequeue());
    }
    lock (orderUpdatesLock)
    {
        while (!args.orderUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            orderUpdates.Enqueue(args.orderUpdates.Dequeue());
    }
    lock (quotesLock)
    {
        while (!args.quotesQueue.IsNullOrEmpty())
            quotes.Enqueue(args.quotesQueue.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

Code will be executed in 1 second.

The question is how to rewrite the code so:

- if some lock can not be acquired then other locks are processing
- no extra thread created (because that would be too expensive).

Likely I should write very complicated `while` loop with a lot of `TryEnter` methods. Or what would be better?

**upd** in reallity lock is holded for very short period of time (about 5-15 microseconds). so it's likely not a good idea to go to another thread, I think everything should be done in the same thread.

Comment: Why don't you want to create extra threads.  If you're talking about waiting a few extra seconds on an additional lock then you'll most certainly save by paralleizing everything, especially if you utilize the thread pool.

Comment: Why have you ruled out creating multiple threads?  Threads are only expensive to create if you are creating them over and over.  Here you would create a dispatch thread per queue once up front and leave to run.

Comment: @Servy i've talked about seconds just for example. in real life every lock is busy for 5-10 microseconds or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these tasks have no dependency on each other at all it would be best to paralleize them.

Here is one way of doing that:

```
Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions(), () =>
    {
        lock (securitiesLock)
        {
            while (!args.securitiesUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
                securities.Enqueue(args.securitiesUpdates.Dequeue());
        }
    },
    () =>
    {
        lock (orderUpdatesLock)
        {
            while (!args.orderUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
                orderUpdates.Enqueue(args.orderUpdates.Dequeue());
        }
    },
    () =>
    {
        lock (quotesLock)
        {
            while (!args.quotesQueue.IsNullOrEmpty())
                quotes.Enqueue(args.quotesQueue.Dequeue());
        }
    });
```

Since you're talking about locks being held for fairly long periods of time, this is quite likely to be a net win.  Since it will rely on thread pool threads (and so most likely won't even need to create 3 hard threads, although it could use them if they're already there) you can eliminate much of the threading overhead.  If nothing else, it's one option to benchmark against the current option and any other solution you create.

Comment: sorry i've talked about "seconds' only as example. didn't realized that it's important. in my real application lock is hold for 5-10 microseconds or so. and yes i still want to win extra 5-15 microseconds in method.

Comment: @javapowered So you've benchmarked a parallelized example against a non-parlleled example and found it to be slower?

Comment: i think i can do everything using `TryEnter` and without threads, but code will be probably too complicated....

Comment: @javapowered If you do that you'll be spinwaiting, which is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: sorry I'm writhing HFT application. as HFT developer i do create extra threads only when absolutely necessary. i don't need to benchmark to know that it would not be fastest solution.

Comment: just passing data to another thread will spend about 10 microseconds as far as I know that's why i don't want to go to another thread.

Comment: @javapowered Rather than guessing, which has a very high tendency to be wrong even by knowledgeable programmers, when you already have two code samples you should just run them and see.

Comment: it's not neccocary to SpinWait. i can just execute "free" lock as a first step. then in the worst case i will "block" at 2 locks of 3 - that is not so bad, isn't it?

Comment: @javapowered If you already know what you want to do, how to do it, and plan to reject all answers that don't conform to what you're planning why ask the question in the first place?  Are you just hoping someone will implement the solution you've outlined for you because you don't want to?

Comment: i only rejecting wrong answers. going to another thread is not good idea when we talking about 5-15 microseconds, taking into account it's possile to do the same things staying in current thread.

Comment: @javapowered While we're on the subject, chances are such a small amount of time isn't the primary bottleneck for a program.  If you are having performance problems there are most certainly other aspects of the program that could benefit much more from your attention.  Also if you're refusting to even attempt to try the answer then it's not "wrong".  If you've tried it and found it to be slower than another existing option, then you can claim it's not preferable (which is still different from "wrong").

Comment: this is not primary bottleneck of couse but still significant place. in HFT every microsecond everywhere makes sense :) i need to return from callback asap so new market data can be collected. also I think it's an interesting question and why not speed up this single part of code at least for fun? if it is not possible or too hard I will left it as is.

Comment: In virtually *any* application every microsecond *doesn't* count.  In the vast majority of code even milliseconds doesn't count, although you're likely in the exceptional category where that might matter.  There's still several orders of magnitude difference there.

Comment: in HFT millisecond is an INFINITY. best systems tick to trade is 10 microseconds (of course they are not wrote on c#)